# Setting the correct grids in QGIS 3.8 map composer?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, grids-graticules

My area lies between E 92.25-92.50 and N 24.50-24.75. When I tried to draw the coordinates on QGIS 3.8 map composer, it showed the co ordinates as E 8.00-E 24.000 and N 0.000-16.000. I used the correct coordinates and projections but the problem still persists. I took "Decimal with suffix" and used "cm" or "mm" as the interval units. But that should not be a problem because the layer and the project are in the same projections. Please show with illustration how to fix this problem. QGIS grid outines are attached.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, no, there's nothing attached.

Comment: I tried to attach but there is some error with this. Trying to do it again

Comment: Well, your map doesn't show anything, have you made sure you zoomed in on your canvas content?

Comment: Map does have content, I removed the content as it can not be shown here. It is an ongoing work.The issue is with the grid not with map content.

Comment: Educated guess: You try to force the map grid into a CRS different from your project's CRS.

Comment: No not at all. Both map and project are in the same projection and CRS. Some people told me its a bug in QGIS.

Comment: I'm talking about the grid specifically. Is your project in EPSG 4326?

Comment: Yes exactly, my project is in EPSG 4326 ;WGS 84 UTM 46 N

Comment: So what is it? EPSG 4326, or UTM 46N aka EPSG 32646?

Comment: What I am aiming at: Your grid seems to need to be in the same CRS as your project. Either your use 4326 for the project, or you use 32646 for the grid. And yes, this is a bit "buggy" in QGIS.

Comment: I tried all the possibilities but still it didn't work. Any way thanks for the reply. If you can find a perfect solution for this problem kindly let me know.

Comment: What does "all the possibilities" mean for you?

Comment: I mean reprojecting the map and changing the grid parameters like map units etc.

Comment: Specifically asking: Did you change the CRS of the grid to the CRS of the project?

Comment: Yes I did, If u want I can send you the points and you can check it in QGIS 3.8 map composer and then may be you can find out what is the real issue.I send it to one of my friends and he also faced the sme issue.

Comment: Feel free to attach sample data to your question =)

Comment: These are the 15 points I want to map in QGIS 3.8 map composer with correct coordinates and grids:  1(24.68242778, 92.43332778), 2(24.68221667, 92.42081944), 3(24.68188333, 92.42177222), 4(24.68142222, 92.42889444),  5(24.68136667, 92.43005), 6(24.68046944, 92.43201389), 7(24.68399167, 92.43201389), 8(24.68443333, 92.44380833), 9(24.68352778, 92.44326944), 10(24.64626389, 92.43345556), 11(24.64425278, 92.43467222),  12(24.64545833, 92.43581389),  13(24.72671667, 92.46151944),  14(24.72721111, 92.46133889) and 15(24.72639167, 92.46071944). If you can map correctly plz show with illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Disclaimer: I worked with QGIS 3.4, since this is the current LTR.

Anyway, I used your points, which are in EPSG 4326, my project was in the same CRS, I set the grid to it also. The display was only correct, when I chose `mapunits` for the interval and set it to a fitting low value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. I think the error on my part was taking "mm" "cm" in place of map units.Thank you once again for this.

Comment: I tried and it worked well. I was struggling with this issue for the last two weeks. God bless you for this Kind help. Thanks a lot.